# Site title not showing. Please help me

Tags: php, functions, css, errors, title

Please help me, My WordPress site's title not showing. It's just displaying the domain like, www.example.com. site: https://happyygarden.com
Please check my site code and suggest how to display the normal title tag.

Comment: Please close your **<title>** tag in header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this code in Header.php file.

```
<title><?php wp_title(' - ', true, 'right'); ?></title>
```

But as per page view source code.you have forgot to close  tag above  tag in header. so please close  tag. see this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/n2yw2s)

**Should code like this:**

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
</script>
<title><?php wp_title(' - ', true, 'right'); ?></title>
```

Comment: OMG!!! thank you a lot Tanmay, It's Work ^^ you are so nice, you made my day, men, thank again Tanmay ^^ ^^

Comment: @HappyyGarden Thank you for this. please mark (tick) as green mark of my answer as well as click on up arrow for "This answer is useful" so it can help for someone which is finding like this.